# How can I refresh Pool processes reading from Queue?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using multiprocessing Pool + Queue to share processing work between a parent process (processing with GPUs) and child processes (processing on the CPU). My program looks like this:

```
def reader_proc(queue):
    ## Read from the queue; this will be spawned as a separate Process
    while True:
        msg = queue.get()         # Read from the queue and do nothing
        do_cpu_work(msg)
        if (msg == 'DONE'):
            break

if __name__=='__main__':
    queue = JoinableQueue()
    pool = Pool(reader_proc, target=(queue,))
    for task in GPUWork:
        results = do_task(task)
        for result in results:
            queue.put(task)
    # put 'DONE' on and join and close
```

I'm having a severe memory leak right now, even after explicitly deleting every variable in the reader_proc and calling gc.collect(). I'm calling into various C++ libraries from the reader_proc and I suspect one of them could be leaking memory. While I try and debug that, I need to get some processing done on this data.

Is there any way to refresh these reader processes? E.g. periodically terminate them and restart them. This exists with `maxtasksperchild` for a Pool operating on an iter but doesn't seem to apply to this Queue / Process based scheme.

Comment: ***"periodically terminate them and restart them"***: Not the `process` self, but within the process doing `queue.put('STOP')`, `queue.put('START')`

Comment: So something like periodically put "DONE"s on the queue, queue.join(), pool.terminate(), restart pool?